# Idiom on a person who sleeps late at night and wake up early in the morning

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

We use the "night owl" idiom for a person who go to sleep late at night, and the "early bird" for those who wake up early in the morning.

Is there any *idiom* for a person who goes to sleep late at night (2 AM) *and* wakes up early in the morning (6 AM)?

Comment: ***exhausted***

Comment: @DanBron Is exhausted an idiom? I want idiom. I think the meaning of exhausted is very tired.

Comment: @SillyNinja "exhausted": Humour… if you give that some thought…

Comment: How about _insomniac_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They **burn the candle at both ends**.

> The idiom was translated from French in 1611. It can be found in
> Randal Cotgrave’s dictionary. Initially the idiom meant that one was
> dissipating one’s wealth. Meaning that you were causing your money to
> disappear. This is because candles were expensive and burning them
> cost money. If you were burning the candle at both ends you were being
> wasteful. You would also have to hold the candle horizontally, leading
> to the wax dripping off and being wasted.
>
> The idiom has since taken on a different meaning. Both ends refer to
> the end and beginning of the day. If you have to light a candle then
> we assume it is dark outside. Thus, if you burn it in the morning you
> are up before the sun and if you burn it at night it is already dark
> when you finish.

[[theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/burn-the-candle-at-both-the-ends/)]

Comment: "My candle burns at both ends;
    It will not last the night;
But ah, my foes, and oh, my friends—
    It gives a lovely light!" -- Edna St. Vincent Millay